# Multisite Manager and Assets Duplication Problem

Tags: assets, multi-site-manager

We added MSM to a site where Assets is used to manage the images on the default site.

When creating a new site and duplicating the channel info etc. everything is duplicating apart from the Assets data.

Is this due to Assets being a custom fieldtype?

Many thanks
Jonny

Answer (score 1):

Jonny.  Yes, the settings should copy over, but unfortunately, the data won't.  There isn't a hook in there for us to add that ability cleanly; you would need to hack the data duplication in.